# Ansible community.general.homebrew module doesn't install any of the packages listed in name. output is just "changed: [localhost]"

Tags: ansible, homebrew, zsh

I've got the following ansible task set up to install a bunch of packages locally via brew:

```
- name: Install general packages
  community.general.homebrew:
    name:
      - neovim
      - ansible-lint
...
      - vim
      - watch
      - wget
      - yaml-language-server
      - zsh
      - zsh-autosuggestions
    state: present
  tags:
    - home
    - work
  async: 300
  poll: 0
```

but the resulting output of running `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --diff --tags home` is just this

```
TASK [brew : Install general packages] *****************************************
changed: [localhost]
```

but none of the packages end up installed on the machine. This causes another play to fail later because the `zsh` package hasn't been installed.

```
- name: Install oh-my-zsh
  ansible.builtin.command: zsh /tmp/install-oh-my-zsh.sh
  when: not oh_my_stats.stat.exists
  tags:
    - home
    - work
```

The failure from this is `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "zsh /tmp/install-oh-my-zsh.sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'zsh'", "rc": 2, "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`async` with no polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0) to run this task:

```
  async: 300
  poll: 0
```

This means that errors returned by the module are not shown and do not cause the play to abort, and further means that the install task may not have completed by the time your followup task that depends on it runs.

Comment: That worked, I suppose I misunderstood the function of those flags. Thanks!